# <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

Tags: python, urllib

The problem here is that whenever I try to do `urlopen` request with `urllib` this problem pops up. I have no idea what could be causing this, maybe an outside source has ip banned me from sending `urllib` requests? Maybe, since when I try to execute the same line of code on my laptop it runs perfectly.
Keep in mind that my laptop is not in the same network as my server where the code is erroring out.

I have tried to do this on all of my other servers that I have and `urllib` works perfectly. The thing is that this error just popped out one day when I ran the code on the server. No code was changed, it just decided to show that error.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen("http://example.com/").read()
```

I expect the `urlopen` request to return readable html data but instead, it returns me this error:

> urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary 
>           failure in name resolution

Comment: Most likely a result of the DNS setup on the system where you are seeing the error. Maybe it doesn't resolve external domains (anymore). Is the system connected to the public internet at all? Are there firewalls in place that filter DNS lookups?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The problem here was that the /etc/resolv.conf file was non-existent and the solution to that was to create it and add, "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to the file. After that and rebooting the server, everything came back to normal.