# What does this error urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Try again> mean?

Tags: python, urllib

I have periodically got this error during request to Shopify REST API. For request I use https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api

If I retry request its o, but error can be occure later again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<urlopen error \[Errno -3\] Temporary failure in name resolution>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353810/urlopen-error-errno-3-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution)

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that this is not tech support. If you have a question that is specific to messages that you get from an API, you should *read the documentation*, and failing that, contact the author. If you believe the problem is more generally with your code than specifically your understanding of the API, then you can ask a question about that; but we can only help you with code that you actually show to us. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Joe , no this is another case. If I retry request its o, but error can be occure later again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.